# Pass arguments to Silverlight OOB app

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

We have a Silverlight application that requires access to peripheral devices - specifically, scanners.  With this requirement, we're forced to use Silverlight as an OOB application.  Up  until recently we have been hosting our silverlight app online inside a .aspx page.  We've been passing parameters to this application through the url (i.e., http://testsite.com/default.aspx?username=User&password=UserPassword&screen=Screen ). The SL app validates the username and password and if authenticated, opens up the "Screen" passed to it.

What options do I have to get this SL application working similar to the way I delineated above (as an OOB)?

Thanks,

-Tom

Comment: I really, really hope you are not seriously putting passwords in the URL like that...

Comment: No, we will obfuscate and encrypt the parameters passed to the application.  Unless, you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing data in via the URL, you could have the application call back to a web service on startup to request this data.  Or store it in Isolated Storage (but I don't recommend putting passwords there, Isolated Storage is not secure) and use that on startup.

Even if there was another way to pass start params to the OOB app how would you want a user to invoke this?  Via some sort of link?  A custom shortcut you create?  Since a user launches an OOB app via the Start menu or desktop only, I'm not understanding what context would even really be available in these cases.

Comment: We have an accounting application that will open up the Silverlight screen.  The parameters we want passed to the SL app are stored in configuration files (each company has its own CorpID and Token among other credentials).  When they click on a menu item that corresponds to a SL screen, we want to make sure the application opens seamlessly w/o requiring the end-user to manually type in their "token" and "corp id".

Comment: I see - that should be pretty easy.  At install time (when your application gets an InstallStateChanged event, or when you call Application.Current.Install()), you could take the CorpID and Token that you're using then (presumably from the URL, or InitParams - doesn't matter) and write it to Isolated Storge.  You may want to encrypt it - your call.  Then, when the app is run, it can check Application.IsRunninOutOfBrowser, and if true look up the values in Iso Store instead of in the URL/InitParams.

Comment: How would one go about passing in the "Screen" that needs to be opened?  Each menu item corresponds to a different screen.  So if the user clicks on the "About" menu item, the "About" screen in Silverlight needs to be opened.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this - the OOB app would be the whole application, right?  They wouldn't install the app once per screen.  So when the user opens the OOB app from their desktop/start menu, presumably it should start at a home screen each time, or maybe remember what screen was last visited (by keeping that info in Iso Store too).

Comment: The SL app will be accessed in multiple ways.  It can be accessed via the web (w/ scanners only available when run OOB) and through our accounting package.  When run through our accounting package, we don't want the end-user to pass in this information that we have stored.  Furthermore, if the user selects a SL screen we want to open up just that particular screen.  This may seem overly complex, but it needs to work this way.

Comment: I am really still not understanding, sorry.  So let's back up - when the user double-clicks the icon on their desktop, what is supposed to open up?  Will it be the same screen each time they double-click the icon?

Comment: No it's okay - and I really do appreciate your help.  The user will not access this app via a desktop.  Our accounting package will launch the SL application.  For example - they launch our accounting package.  There's a menu item called, "Scanners".  When they click "Scanners", I want it to open up the "Scanners" screen in our SL application.  Similarly, they could click "About" and that would open the "About" screen in the SL application.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, keep in mind - our menus are written with windows forms.  So the SL application would need to be launched within a windows forms application.

Comment: Oh, I see - that's the piece I was missing!  So, there's no way to directly pass parameters (as you saw) but how about this: the accounting software could host a local web service on some well-known port (say,localhost:98765, or whatever).  I leave security up to you on that part.  That local web service could be called by the SL app when it starts up in OOB mode to find out what its "current context" should be, which would include the screen and anything else necessary to make it feel rather seemless.

Comment: Or, alternatively, have you considered hosting the SL app inside the accounting software directly, rather than launching a separate OOB app that has to get installed?  If the accounting package hosted the app (with a WebBrowser control in WinForms) you could let the two talk to each other via the HTML DOM bridge.  Then they have a 2-way channel that should be fairly straightforward, and the end-user shouldn't even notice that there are two apps present.

Comment: Thanks Austin for all your help!  Your suggestions have definitely helped us out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you install a Silverlight application to run OOB, it creates a directory in isolated storage which has an index.htm page in it that actually "hosts" the OOB application.  (It's described here: http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2009/07/17/silverlight-3-outofbrowseroob-explained-and-how-to-host-any-xap-package-by-modifying-the-metadata/).  One way to do what you need to do is to edit that index.htm page, and pass in the parameters there.  Of course, you'd need to figure out how to edit that page (likely hard to do automatically, unless you've got a setup.exe).  Would it make more sense to just prompt the user for their userid/password?  You'd only need to do it once -- after that, you could store it in a configuration file in some well-known location (presumably encrypted or at least obfuscated in some fashion).

Comment: FYI, it is strongly discouraged to rely on the implementation details of the OOB application cache like this.  We (the Silverlight team) do not document this stuff for a reason - because it may change.  I would advise anyone to assume this is a black box and not mess with it.

Comment: Good point. But do you have a better suggestion? Is there a better/supported way to pass command-line parameters to an OOB Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0):

The other possibility, if you are using Silverlight 4, is to store values into the Windows Registry.  This is what we are using for username, database name, etc..